# Getting more records after converting inner query to joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an inner query

```
select * from ASSETVERSION  where id in (
    select ASSETVERSION_ID from scene_asset where scene_id in(
        select scene_id from contentobject_scene where contentobject_id in(
            select id from contentobject where course_id = 34660
        )
    )     
)
and LOCATION is not null
```

when i run this query i get 27 records. Now i coverted this query to joins like

```
select av.* from ASSETVERSION av
inner join scene_asset sa on av.id = sa.assetversion_id
inner join scene s on s.id = sa.scene_id
inner join contentobject_scene co_s on s.id = co_s.scene_id
inner join contentobject co on co.id = co_s.contentobject_id
inner join course c on c.id = co.course_id 
where
    c.id = 34660
    and av.location is not null
```

when i run this query i get 36 records. When i change from `av.*` to `distinct av.*` the i get 27 records as returning by the inner query.

when i change from `distinct av.*` to `distinct av.id, av.asset_id, av.location, co.name as "Content Object name", s.name as "Scene Name" from ASSETVERSION av`, then i again get 36 records.

`distinct av.id, av.asset_id, av.location --, co.name as "Content Object name", s.name as "Scene Name"  from ASSETVERSION av` works fine. Mean return 27 records.

Is there any way i can apply distinct to `co.name as "Content Object name", s.name as "Scene Name"` like

```
select distinct av.id, av.asset_id, av.location, distinct co.name as "Content Object name",  distinct s.name as "Scene Name" 
from ASSETVERSION av ...
```

so i get the same 27 records as return by the inner query ?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @DanBracuk I get an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.` when i try `select distinct av.id, av.asset_id, av.location, distinct co.name as "Content Object name", distinct s.name as "Scene Name ..." . Thanks
    from ASSETVERSION av...`

Comment: Distinct should only be used once in your query -- select distinct field1, field2, field3, etc...

Comment: @sgeddes yes i tried also `select distinct av.id, av.asset_id, av.location, co.name as "Content Object name", s.name as "Scene Name" 
    from ASSETVERSION av ...` but in this case i am getting the 36 records, instead of 27 as returning by inner query.

Comment: I posted an answer, but it really depends on your desired results.  This is how Joins work -- check out the link I supplied for more information.  Sample data and desired results would help address your issue.

Comment: @Basit - You have privileges for voting so use it. You have asked 170+ questions and answered almost 20 questions. But your voting is only 8?

Comment: @hims056 voting privileges for what ? i mark the answer accepted when i get the answer... ?

Comment: @Basit, don't worry about voting.  Just because you can doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: @Basit - Have a look at [vote-up](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and [vote-down](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). But it's on you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this issue because there are multiple records in your contentobject and/or scene tables that join to your assetversion table.  Because of this, you will get duplicated assetversion results, but distinct contentobject and/or scene results.

[Visual Representation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

What are your desired results?  If you only want to return a single record from the joined tables, you may need to use an aggregate such as `MAX`.  Or if you want to show the results in the same column (comma delimited for example), since you're using SQL Server (assuming 2005 or higher), you can look into using `FOR XML`.  Really depends at this point on your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty standard way of doing a JOIN and ensuring only one row, before SQL 2005, was like this:

```
...
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.PK=(
  SELECT TOP 1 PK 
  FROM Table2
  WHERE FK=t1.PK
  ORDER BY SomeColumn)
...
```

Now with SQL 2005+ you can use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.PK, ORDER BY SomeColumn)
```

and select only those rows where the Row Number=1